# Pythonic way to verify if is json or python dict

Tags: python, json

I need to verify if 'info' is a json file or a python dict. Given the fact that the json file and the python dict has the same structure I wrote this code to parse both and save their content in a variable but I think there is a pythonic and more efficient code.

```
import json

class LoadInfo(object):
def __init__(self, info=None):
    if info:
        try:
            self.config= json.loads(info)
        except ValueError:
            print('Load Python Dict')
            try:
                if isinstance(info, dict):
                    self.config= info
            except ValueError:
                print('Json or python dict config is needed')
    else:
        raise Exception('Json or python dict config is needed')

info  = LoadInfo('path/to/json_file') #should work
info_dict = dict('A'=1, 'B'=2, 'C'=3)
info2 = LoadInfo(info_dict) #Also should work
```

Anyone has more ideias?

Comment: IMO you should restructure your code. Why can't you simply load the data outside `LoadInfo` class and pass the result to it? Why `LoadInfo` should accept two different types under one param?

Comment: Why would you write code that either takes a dictionary or a JSON string? I would write a classmethod `def from_json(cls, info): return cls(json.loads(info))`. That way you only deal with the dictionary case in `__init__`. Also you should never just `raise Exception:`; if the `info` parameter is required, *don't give it a default value*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, don't just `raise Exception`; that's far too general, be as specific as you can about what has gone wrong. In this case, it's that the user hasn't provided the `info` parameter. Two problems with that:

1. You should test for `None` by identity, not truthiness (otherwise e.g. `{}` would be an exception, which may not be what you actually want): `if info is not None:`.
2. If it's a required parameter, *why give it a default value?!*

Revision 1:

```
import json

class LoadInfo(object):

    def __init__(self, info):
        try:
            self.config = json.loads(info)
        except ValueError:
            print('Load Python Dict')
            try:
                if isinstance(info, dict):
                    self.config = info
            except ValueError:
                print('python dict config is needed')
```

*(Note minor [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) tweaks.)*

---

Next, there's really no need to provide this kind of polymorphism by allowing either a dictionary or a JSON string as the argument. As in the second case you're just parsing it to the first case, make that a class method, which is the common alternate constructor pattern in Python.

Revision 2:

```
import json

class LoadInfo(object):

    def __init__(self, info):
        try:
            if isinstance(info, dict):
                self.config = info
        except ValueError:
            print('python dict config is needed')

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, info):
        return cls(json.loads(info))
```

---

Which part of:

```
if isinstance(info, dict):
    self.config = info
```

do you expect to raise a `ValueError`? And why, in the case where it's not an acceptable type of input, would you want to just `print` something and let the program continue? Note that where you're checking types, it's better to use the [ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

Revision 3:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
import json

class LoadInfo(object):

    def __init__(self, info):
        if not isinstance(info, Mapping):
            raise TypeError('mapping config is needed')
        self.config = info

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, info):
        return cls(json.loads(info))
```

---

But actually, you're suggesting that it be loaded from a file, not the JSON string as your current code implies (you provide `'path/to/json_file'` not `'{"foo": "bar"}'` - it's not clear what you expected `json.loads` to make of that). So you need to handle that file.

Revision 4:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
import json

class LoadInfo(object):

    def __init__(self, info):
        if not isinstance(info, Mapping):
            raise TypeError('mapping config is needed')
        self.config = info

    @classmethod
    def from_json_file(cls, filename):
        with open(filename) as json_file:
            return cls(json.load(json_file))  # note 'load' not 'loads'
```

---

Now your examples become:

```
info = LoadInfo.from_json_file('path/to/json_file')
info_dict = dict(A=1, B=2, C=3)  # note you shouldn't use quotes for keys here
info2 = LoadInfo(info_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to open a file object at first if you pass a file and it will be better to separate file and string arguments:

```
import os
import json

class LoadInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, info=None, file=None):
        if file and os.path.exists(file):
            with open(file) as f:
                data = f.read()
            try:
                self.config = json.loads(data)
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError('Load JSON file error')
        elif info:
            if isinstance(info, dict):
                self.config = info
            elif isinstance(info, str):
                try:
                    self.config = json.loads(info)
                except ValueError:
                    raise ValueError('Load JSON string error')
        else:
            raise ValueError('Load config error')
```

I would split it into two methods:

```
class LoadInfo(object):
    def load_from_file(self, file):
        with open(file) as f:
            data = f.read()
        self.config = json.loads(data)

    def load_from_str(self, info):
        if isinstance(info, dict):
           self.config = info
        elif isinstance(info, str):
            self.config = json.loads(info)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Load config error')
```

But actually, it's more pythonic to use ducktyping style.